# Command not working in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When I run the command below on my Citrix server in a CMD window it works fine, but when I run it in a batch file I get "was unexpected at this time"

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=: " %f in ('nslookup www.domain.com ^| find /i "Address"') do ALTADDR /SET %f
```

How do I get this to work in a batch file?

Answer (score 4):

In a batch file you have to use %%f instead of %f:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=: " %%f in ('nslookup www.domain.com ^| find /i "Address"') do ALTADDR /SET %%f
```

Comment: Thanks! I was always curious, why there's sometimes '%' and sometimes '%%'. This used to be a little WTF moment for me.

Comment: Yes, I know... Escaping special chars is - ahm - ugly. But it gets really weird, if you have to escape escape chars... ^^